# Take invertible matrix $A$, and set a diagonal entry of $A$ to $\infty$. Can we use $A^{-1}$ to find the pseudo inverse of this new matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, computer-science

Consider having $A$, with $A^{-1}$ previously calculated.

Say I apply a rank 1 update on $A$ using $v = (\infty,0,0,0,0)$:
$${B} = vv^T A $$

Clearly A is no longer invertible, but the pseudo inverse still exists.

We can apply the sherman morrison formula ${\displaystyle \left(A+vv^{\textsf {T}}\right)^{-1}=A^{-1}-{A^{-1}vv^{\textsf {T}}A^{-1} \over 1+v^{\textsf {T}}A^{-1}v}.}$

However, the denominator here is obviously not well defined.

Is there another route to efficiently calculate the pseudo inverse of $B$?

We have the standard formula for inverting 2x2 block matrices, i.e for S invertible,

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
    C &D  \\
    E&F
\end{bmatrix}
$$
If $C^{-1}$ or $F^{-1}$ exist, then we can compute $S^{-1}$. In our case, $F^{-1}$ must exist so we can write

$$B=\begin{bmatrix}
    \infty &D  \\
    E&F
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$B^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}
    0 &0  \\
    0&F^{-1}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

However, we would like to be able to calculate $B^{-1}$ without first computing $F^{-1}$ - in general the index of the value that is set to $\infty$ is not known, so this would still require computing the inverse of a $(n-1)\times(n-1)$ matrix.

Comment: You can't really just set it to be "$\infty.$" What you can do is set it to be some number $N$, compute the expression then send $N \to \infty.$

Comment: @AlanChung sure, yes, i appreciate the question is pretty handwavy - i am asking whether the limit is efficiently computable

Comment: what is the problem exactly? It seems you already have an expression for the quantity you want to compute. Are you having difficulty taking $N \to \infty$?

Comment: I'm interested specifically in an _efficient_ computational method for calculating $B^{-1}$ in the case that I have already computed $A^{-1}$. e.g in the case that $A$ is modified by a rank-1 update and remains invertible, the sherman-morrison formula has much better computational complexity than direct computation of the inverse (assuming that $A^{-1}$ is already known). eg maybe I can calculate something interesting by considering the limit in the sherman morrison formula & applying l'hopitals?

Comment: Yeah like, I'm saying that you already have an expression for $(A + v v^T)^{-1}.$ What is the problem with then taking $N \to \infty$?

Comment: @AlanChung thanks for the prompting, seems like this just works. I thought I was going to run into an issue on the limit for some reason

Comment: great! glad it worked

Comment: what was the answer btw? I'm just curious

Comment: I'll write this as an answer @AlanChung

Answer (score 0):

Computation of the above:

Let $v = (k,0,0)$ for simplicity

Then we can calculate: $1+v^TA^{-1}v^T$ = $1+k^2A^{-1}_{11}$

$$
A^{-1}v v^T A^{-1} =(v^TA^{-T})^{T}v^T A^{-1} = k^2\cdot B\cdot D,\text{ where}
$$

$$
D = \cdot \begin{bmatrix} 
    Row_1(A) \\
    0 \\
    ... \\
    0
\end{bmatrix},
$$
$$
B = \cdot \begin{bmatrix} 
    Col_1(A) & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

i.e $D_{ij} = \begin{cases}
    A_{ij},& \text{if } j=1 \\
    0,              & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases},$
$B_{ij} = \begin{cases}
    A_{ij},& \text{if } i=1 \\
    0,              & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$

Then

$$(A+vv^T)^{-1} =A^{-1} -  \frac{k^2}{1+k^2A^{-1}_{11}} BD
$$

Now, as $k\to+\infty$, the fraction tends to $1/A^{-1}_{11}$.